# How to pass curl post request where there is an array in data?

Tags: arrays, curl

I need to pass in Okta data to my application:

```
url: "www.okta.com"
groups: ["g1", "g2"]
```

Now, how do I structure curl request to send an array?

```
curl --digest --user abc -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --request POST -d ' {"url":"www.okta.com", "groups": **????** }' url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data payload is just JSON? Wouldn't you simply include the array as an element of the data object?

```
curl --digest --user abc -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --request POST -d ' {"url":"www.okta.com", "groups": ["g1", "g2"]}' url
```